# Viewing large number of pictures over network storage

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to view a large number of images from a NAS on a MacBook Air.

So far I open the folder in Finder, select all the images, and double click on the first one. This opens the image and I can use arrow keys to move to the next image. This is basically what I want.

However there is a problem. If I open a folder with many images, because the viewer seems to load all images at once which takes a long time over the network (from the NAS on the LAN).

Is there a way to load the images on demand such that it just opens the image currently viewed? (and perhaps preload the next one in the background?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Quick Look](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25575?locale=en_US). Select all the images, press <kbd>spacebar</kbd> and use the arrow keys to view the images.

Comment: Yep. Exactly what I was going to say. This works pretty well but the pictures will still have to load. The speed at which they load is controlled but the speed of the NAS drive, the internet speed of both the NAS Drive and yourself, and the speed of the drive your viewing it on.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Quick Look only loads the current image. On the plus side, you don't have to wait for all the images to open. On the minus side, it doesn't seem to preload the next image.